# Fetch column names in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table, which sets a lot of "ranks" for my latest project. For every user, there is a row in that table, that has a bunch of `enums` in it. For example:

`userid | guardian | mage | assassin | hunter|
 1      | 0        | 1    | 1        | 0     |`

(There are a lot more in the actual database.)

Now on a users profile, I'd like to show his/her ranks. Normally I'd query it like so:

`SELECT COUNT(id) AS id FROM ranks WHERE userid = 1 AND mage = 1`

But since I have alot of columns here, it seems a bit overwhelming.

Is there a way to use the actual column name? I'm using PHP for my backend, just so you know.

Comment: Why not normalise your design?

Comment: @Strawberry Normalize it as in make in one single column?

Comment: @Strawberry Would you mind posting an example?

Comment: @strawberry So rank for example would become 1,1 and then explode it at the comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A normalised environment might look like this:

```
userid*, character*, rank
  1      guardian      0    
  1      mage          1 
  1      assassin      1   
  1      hunter        0

* = (component of) PRIMARY KEY
```

But I'm not going to explain normalisation to you. It's a big topic, thoroughly covered elsewhere, and I might make a mistake.